# Routes related with nics

Tags: powershell

I'm using

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable
```

to get the persisted route entries, I need to relate those route entries with the interface that they re associated with, any way to return NIC for each correspondent persisted route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PowerShell code issue or limitation. This is a .Net limitation. There is no property in this class that allows you to identify the associated NIC interface.

[Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmiiprouteprov/win32-ip4persistedroutetable)

The operating system stores persistent routes in the registry... This class is only applicable to IPv4 and does not return IPX or IPv6 data.

```
[dynamic, provider("RouteProvider"), UUID("{2CAF4666-AC9B-45AB-00A6-AF8C537794C2}"), SupportsCreate, CreateBy("PutInstance"), SupportsDelete, DeleteBy("DeleteInstance"), AMENDMENT]
class Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable : CIM_LogicalElement
{
  string   Caption; # This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.
  string   Description;
  string   Destination;
  datetime InstallDate;
  string   Mask;
  sint32   Metric1;
  string   Name;
  string   NextHop;
  string   Status;
};
```

***Update per our below thread***

So, your ask of...

> 'anyway to return NIC for each correspondent persisted route?'

...the answer as I've stated, is a none that I am aware of, via using only what you show. You have to get that data and compare it with other results of other network cmdlets.

> [IPv6 and IPv4 Support in WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/ipv6-and-ipv4-support-in-wmi)
>
> WMI IP Route Provider and network classes supply data for IPv4
>   addresses. Starting with Windows Vista, WMI also provides limited
>   support for IPv6 network capabilities.
>
> WMI IP Data The following classes supply only IPv4 data:

- > Win32_IP4RouteTable
- > Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable
- > Win32_IP4RouteTableEvent
- > Win32_ActiveRoute
- > Win32_NetworkAdapter

PowerShell notwithstanding. Key properties are readable.

VBSCript

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable",,48)

Dim objItem 'as Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable
For Each objItem in colItems
    WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
    WScript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
    WScript.Echo "Destination: " & objItem.Destination
    WScript.Echo "InstallDate: " & objItem.InstallDate
    WScript.Echo "Mask: " & objItem.Mask
    WScript.Echo "Metric1: " & objItem.Metric1
    WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    WScript.Echo "NextHop: " & objItem.NextHop
    WScript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
    WScript.Echo ""
Next
```

> Property Mask As string (read-only)
>
> The Mask property contains the mask used in this persisted entry.
>   Masks should be logical-ANDed with the destination address before
>   being compared to the value in the ipRouteDest field.
>
> Property NextHop As string (read-only)
>
> The NextHop property contains the IP address of the next hop of this
>   persisted route. (In the case of a route bound to an interface that is
>   realized via a broadcast media, the value of this field is the agent's
>   IP address on that interface.).

The tools in Windows (route, netsh, etc...) use the classes to do what they do.

You could just parse the route print command if that has the info you're looking for:

Cmd.exe (DOS) tools to a PowerShell Object

```
$tmpRoute = (route print | ? { $_.trimstart() -like "0.0.0.0*" }).split() | ? { $_ }

$route = @{
            'Destination' = $tmpRoute[0];
            'Netmask'     = $tmpRoute[1];
            'Gateway'     = $tmpRoute[2];
            'Interface'   = $tmpRoute[3];
            'Metric'      = $tmpRoute[4];
          }

$route
```

> [WMI pull it directly from the machine (local or remote):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vpnclientpsprov/msft-netroute-vpnclientpsprovider)

```
$computer = 'localhost'
$wmi = get-wmiobject -namespace root\StandardCimv2 -computername 'localhost' -Query "Select * from MSFT_NetRoute"
$wmi | ? { $_.DestinationPrefix -eq '0.0.0.0/0' } | 
Select DestinationPrefix, InterfaceAlias, InterfaceIndex, InterfaceMetric, NextHop, RouteMetric
```

> [See this script...](https://github.com/zloeber/Powershell/blob/master/OS/Multiple%20Runspace/Get-RemoteRouteTable.ps1)

... showing direct WMI calls to that namespace...

```
# WMI data
$wmi_routes = Get-WmiObject @WMIHast -Class win32_ip4RouteTable
$wmi_persistedroutes = Get-WmiObject @WMIHast -Class win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable
foreach ($iproute in $wmi_routes)
{
    $Persistant = $false
    foreach ($piproute in $wmi_persistedroutes)
    {
        if (($iproute.Destination -eq $piproute.Destination) -and
            ($iproute.Mask -eq $piproute.Mask) -and
            ($iproute.NextHop -eq $piproute.NextHop))
        {
            $Persistant = $true
        }
    }
    $RouteProperty = @{
        'InterfaceIndex' = $iproute.InterfaceIndex
        'Destination' = $iproute.Destination
        'Mask' = $iproute.Mask
        'NextHop' = $iproute.NextHop
        'Metric' = $iproute.Metric1
        'Persistent' = $Persistant
        'Type' = $RouteType[[int]$iproute.Type]
    }
    $Routes += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $RouteProperty
}
...
```

Or even using that class to directly set persistent routes.

```
# Set objWMIClass = objWMIServices.Get (cWMIIPPersistedRouteClass)
$class = gwmi -list win32_ip4persistedroutetable -EnableAll -Computer remotehost1

#Set objWMIPersistentInstance = objWMIClass.SpawnInstance_
$newroute = $class.CreateInstance()

#objWMIPersistentInstance.Destination = strDestination
$newroute.Destination = $destination

#objWMIPersistentInstance.Mask = strMask
$newroute.Mask = $mask

#objWMIPersistentInstance.NextHop = strNextHop
$newroute.NextHop = $nexthop

#objWMIPersistentInstance.Metric1 = intMetric
$newroute.Metric1=$metric

$newroute.Put()

$newroute.Destination='10.10.10.101'
$newroute.Mask='255.255.255.0'
$newroute.NextHop='10.10.10.1'
$newroute.Metric1=30

$newroute.Put()
```

Comment: I never said it was, I just ask how to match a given route with the correspondent NIC

Comment: Well, you also did not show any code of what you've tried and errors you may have encountered. Unless returned objects/output provide comparison properties (or calculated ones), which you also never showed, then it is not possible. I am in no position to test this class in my current environment. So, by extension, you'll need to look at more than just that class for comparison. The closest you may be able to associate is the NetxtHop property, associate that with the NextOp property via Get-NetRoute, and select the ifindex from what Get-NetRoute provides. Even that may not be exact enough.

Comment: ?? The question was if you know a way to match the IpAddress with Get-WmiObject Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable, what code do you want to see? Is the 2nd part that is missing because there is no direct way using Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable, that s why I asked

Comment: What do you mean...' because there is no direct way using Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable'... if a .Net class exists and can be instantiated, then by design it can be accessed, thus why API's/namespaces exists. See the update I made. This is all about research and knowing that you have to look to more than one resource to collect the details you will need to make a decision on the next steps.
Hence my statement regarding ... 'what code do you want to see?'... this means what efforts did you try, or research. Code close to this use case already exists, see my update.